# An object of a resulting type in a closure passed to a Swift resultBuilder

Tags: swift

Why does it compile and work?
I can't find any info on this.

I'll give you an example. Based on SwiftSyntax library.

```
@CodeBlockItemListBuilder statementsBuilder: () -> CodeBlockItemListSyntax
```

So, let's say we have a function with such a parameter. The function expects a closure with CodeBlockItems, and the resultBuilder will build CodeBlockItemList as a result.

```
myFunction {
    item1
    item2
    item3
...
}
```

It appears that I can pass an itemList (an object of the resulting type `CodeBlockItemListSyntax`) to this as well:

```
myFunction {
    itemList
}
```

I don't understand why we're allowed to do that. Why does it work? How does it work?!
In fact, we even can mix Item with ItemList objects! But output is a little bit strange... which confuses me even more.

P.S.
Was pretty surprised that there still doesn't exist neither "result-builder" nor "swift-syntax" tags in StackOverFlow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There simply an overload of `CodeBlockItemListBuilder.buildExpression` that takes a `CodeBlockItemListSyntax`. See the [documentation](https://swiftpackageindex.com/apple/swift-syntax/509.0.2/documentation/swiftsyntaxbuilder/codeblockitemlistbuilder/buildexpression(_:)-9qnu7).

```
static func buildExpression(
    _ expression: CodeBlockItemListBuilder.FinalResult
) -> CodeBlockItemListBuilder.Component
```

[`CodeBlockItemListBuilder.FinalResult`](https://swiftpackageindex.com/apple/swift-syntax/509.0.2/documentation/swiftsyntaxbuilder/codeblockitemlistbuilder/finalresult) is a type alias for `CodeBlockItemListSyntax`.

Presumably, they added this overload because adding new statements to an existing code block is a common thing to do, and this overload makes it more convenient:

```
CodeBlockItemListSyntax {
    "print(\"a new statement!\")"
    someExistingCodeBlock
}
```

Comment: Actually I suspected something like this and was searching for this, but didn't find. Thank you.